# Raster Land Cover Land Use Data added to vector polygon attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, attribute-table

I have a set of 1000 points which I have added a buffer of 100m too. Then I extracted by mask those 1000 points that have the 100m buffer added from a land use land cover (LULC) raster data set. Now I have 1000, 100m circles of raster data. The attribute table for 1000 LULC data still counts the cells of the 1000 different circles as a single item and separates them based on their land class.

I need to have them separated by circle and have the different land classes separated to show how many cells of each land class make up every different circle. I want to be able to see the cells within each circle separately to be able to compare them. I want to add the cell counts of the raster layer to the attribute table of the 100m buffer.
[image: raster][image: buffer][image: tabular area][image: tab area]

Answer (score 1):

The [Tabulate Area (Spatial Analyst)](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/tabulate-area.htm) tool is what you need. The tool accepts both raster and feature layers as zonal input. Just make sure your feature class has a unique ID for each feature (i.e. it is a single part feature class). Finally, join your table to the feature class by feature ID.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I posted some pictures on the original attribute tables of both the raster and vector data that I was trying to combine and the output. It did not work exactly how I wanted. The values are extremely high and it doesn't include all of the 1010 location buffers that I used. Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Could you please look at the buffers that have no value and report the underlying raster condition (e.g. outside of raster area, no data cells, etc)? Also, why do you think the values are high? The tool will grab any raster cells contained within your zone data--some of the raster cells will likely extend beyond the buffer boundary because the 30m cell size.